# replaceAll for StringBuilder with regex support?

Tags: java, regex, string, stringbuilder

I've looked in the Java API and some common 3rd party libraries but I'm unable to find a suitable method that will do what String.replaceAll does, except for StringBuilder.

I know that with a little work, it can be done for StringBuffer, but I don't want to go down this road because StringBuffer is slower.

Does anyone know of any 3rd party utilies, or if there is a quick piece of code to implement this functionality?

Comment: Is it that performance critical or such a large string that converting it to a string and doing the replace (and converting it back if required) is out of the question?

Comment: You can create a `Matcher` (which can be created on any `CharSequence`) and then write a loop with `appendReplacement` and `appendTail` to write your own `replaceAll`.

Comment: Yes but that one uses StringBuffer ...

Comment: In fact, you don't even need all that `append*` magic... `Matcher` provides its own `replaceAll`.

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas I see what you mean now. The `append*` functions take a StringBuffer as well... fair enough.

Answer (score 13):

`String.replaceAll` is just a convenience method for `Matcher.replaceAll`. `Matcher` is the "actual" way to use regex in Java and is allows for a lot more sophisticated use cases.

Moreover, anything that can be done with regex methods on `String` can be done with similar methods on a `Matcher`. The beauty is, that `Matcher`s work with more than just `String`s: `Matcher`s can be obtained for any `CharSequence` (an interface, which is implemented by `StringBuilder`, `StringBuffer`, `String` and `CharBuffer`). So you can simply do:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

...

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("This works with StringBuffers");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\Buffer\\B");
Matcher m = p.matcher(sb);
System.out.println(m.replaceAll("uilder"));
```

Will output `This works with StringBuilders`.

[Working demo.](http://ideone.com/jbAJ3R)

Comment: I'm not sure if OP is for something like this since `m.relaceAll` will internally use StringBuffer and return String with replaced data. I believe that OP wants to know is there a way to use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer like we use it in `Matcher#appendReplacement()` but I may be wrong. OP comment would be better here.

Comment: @Pshemo ah okay, I didn't know that `Matcher` uses a StringBuffer internally.

Comment: Basically I have the following method signature:  `public void replaceAll(final StringBuilder builder, final String regex, final String replacement)`.    The builder's data should be modified without having to do any reassignement.

Answer (score 3):

Regex does not modify a mutable `CharSequence` internally. Regex parses a `CharSequence` to return a `String`, where `String` is the result. `StringBuffer` is an exception as there is special handling - as for `StringBuilder` being `CharSequence`, you have to modify it with a match result.

What you can do instead:

```
// Class
private static final Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("my|regex");

{ // Method
    StringBuilder builder;
    // ...

    Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher(builder);
    builder.replace(0, builder.length(), m.replaceAll("<b>$0</b>"));
}
```

[View a test code demo!](http://ideone.com/4cWacR)

Answer (score 3):

> I don't want to go down this road because StringBuffer is slower.

True, but with the usual premature optimization caveat, and more importantly, [modern JVMs use escape analysis to remove the StringBuffer/Vector/HashTable locks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_performance#Escape_analysis_and_lock_coarsening) in certain cases, so once that optimization happens, the performance will be roughly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Harmony [Matcher source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/harmony/enhanced/java/trunk/classlib/modules/regex/src/main/java/java/util/regex/Matcher.java?revision=979659&view=markup) seems fully reworkable to be used with `StringBuilder` instead of the currently used `StringBuffer`, just move to the different package. It seems not dragging a lot of dependences with it. Apache license that is at the start of the file may not be bad even for commercial project.

[GNU Classpath](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/regex/Matcher-source.html) code can also be reused but the license is more difficult there (you need to publish your changed version of the Matcher but probably not the rest of your code). Same about the original Sun's implementation that can be found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/regex/Matcher.java) in the OpenJDK project.